# Power series as fractions

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, combinatorics, power-series

This is what I did:
\begin{equation*}
(x^3-x^6)x^6[x+x^2+x^3+..], \\
\frac{(x^3-x^6)x^6}{1-x}.
\end{equation*}
What mistake did I make?

And,

How to solve this: $1+3x^2+9x^4+27x^6+...+3^{157}x^{314}$ ? I have tried differentiating and then integrating the sum, I was getting a weird answer. Please help!

Comment: They are both geometric series. The first has first term $x^3$ and common ratio $-x^3$. So the sum is $\frac{x^3}{1-(-x^3)}$ if $|x|\lt 1$. Now identify the common ratio of the second series.

Comment: @AndréNicolas The common ratio for the second one is $3x^2$ and the sum is $1+[\frac {1}{1-3x^2}]$.Am i right?

Comment: There is a typo, you meant $\frac{1}{1-3x^2}$. We also should specify where this is valid, $|x|\lt 1/\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But the second series is an finite series it ends at $x^{314}$ so does this still hold?

Comment: @L887 It doesn't hold. You have to use this: $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{k} = \frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Comment: I did not notice it is a finite series. There is a nice closed form for these too, here valid whenever $1-3x^2\ne 0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Factor $x^3$ out to get $1-x^3+(-x^3)^2 + (-x^3)^3 \pm \ldots$

which is a geometric series.

You can decompose the original one directly as well, using $-x^3$ as the common multiple.

Comment: but what is wrong with what i did?

Comment: @L887 you missed $1$ when factoring out, should be $(x^3-x^6)(1+x+\ldots)$

Comment: @L887 You should also notice that the lowest term in your "simplified version" is $x^{10}$

Comment: Let $t=x^3$, then error is less likely.

Comment: @user222031 indeed, this is how i caught the bug in the first place

Comment: @user222031 fixed, thanks for the correction